# how can i optimize my R code without using loops?

Tags: r

I am a beginner with R and wrote the following piece of code, to copy parts from one table to another according to the condition and it works, but when I try it with very large files it runs very slow and takes a lot of time to finish, how can I optimize the code, maybe use something else that replaces the use of loops?
for example:

```
data1B :

#id    sample_id 
 1         NA
 2         NA
 3         NA
data2:
 #sample_id   #clone_id   
  300            8
  301            3
  302            1 
  400            7
  500            2
output data1B:
#id         #sample_id
 1             302
 2             500
 3             301



  for (i in 1:nrow(data1B)){
    for (j in 1:nrow(data2)){
     if (data1B$id[i] == data2$clone_id[j]){
      data1B$sample_id[i] <- data2$sample_id[j]
     }
   }
  }
```

Comment: Please provide sample data. Read the message at the top of the [r] tag. "Please provide minimal and reproducible example(s) along with the desired output. Use `dput()` for data and specify all non-base packages with `library()` calls. "

Answer (score 0):

```
outer(1:nrow(data1B),1:nrow(data2),function(i,j){
  ifelse(data1B$id[i] == data2$clone_id[j], data2$sample_id[j], data1B$sample_id[i])
})
```

Comment: i had an error "Error: cannot allocate vector of size 32424.9 Gb" which i guess due to memory allocated to R.

Comment: as i mentioned above i am using very large datasets! above 13M rows each. what can use in this case? Thank you.

Comment: @A.SH You may have to use some package made for big data then, because base R is not made for this kind of data.

Comment: Please don't post only code as an answer, but also provide an explanation of what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually of higher quality and are more likely to attract upvotes.